# python manage.py syncdb - Not synced

Tags: база-данных, django

Использую Django 1.6 и Debian. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытаюсь создать таблицу моделей в БД.

На мой запрос `python manage.py syncdb` выдает:

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - admin_tools.menu
 - admin_tools.dashboard
 - online
 - cabinet
 - djcelery
 - constance.backends.database
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

Как синхронизировать?

---

Результат при использовании `# python manage.py migrate`

```
Running migrations for menu:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_initial.
 > menu:0002_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "admin_tools_menu_bookmark" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "user_id" integer NOT NULL, "url" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255) NOT NULL)
The error was: table "admin_tools_menu_bookmark" already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = DROP TABLE "admin_tools_menu_bookmark"; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: menu:0002_initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Я просто не знаю как дальше быть...

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает из-за того что система считает что у приложения menu есть не проведенная миграция 0002_initial, но по какой то причине эта таблица уже есть в базе. Соответственно база при попытке создать уже существующую таблицу отвечает ошибкой "The error was: table "admin_tools_menu_bookmark" already exists".

Что бы решить проблему у вас есть два пути:

1. Если в этой таблице у вас нет ничего важного, удалить ее выполнив запрос   `DROP TABLE "admin_tools_menu_bookmark";` А затем снова запустите команду миграции `python manage.py migrate`
2. Удалите в каталоге приложения menu из папки migrations миграцию вызывающую ошибку, она будет называться как-то вроде `0002_initial.py` и живите дальше спокойно =)

Comment: Дополнил вопрос результатом ввода `python manage.py migrate`.